# How to pass table row value to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 


$.ajax({
    url: "submitTimesheet.php", // php file path
    method: "POST", // send data method
    data: {"alex": i}, // data to send {name: value}
    success: function(response){} // response of ajax



  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
         if(i>1){
         $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
         i--;
         }
     });
});
```

submitTimsheet.php page
$alex = $_POST["alex"];

echo $alex; dosent work
How can i pass the variable into a php page to get the number of times a user added a row ?

Comment: Have you looked into using `ajax` ? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: why don't you use array index in name e.g. `<input  name='mobile[]' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md'>` so in php get value in foreach

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need to post the row count to php... are you running some server-side query? What are your intentions with this count because I get the feeling you don't need to pass this to php and could be handled client-side in javascript/jQuery....

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax, or seeing as this looks like a form, you could use a hidden input field and update its value before the form is submitted

Comment: This doesn't really offer a solid answer, this is more of a suggestion which should be posted as a comment rather than a solution.

Comment: I can't comment, my reputation isn't high enough

Comment: A reputation amount requirement is for a reason on comments. If you misuse the answers/solutions section you will find people downvote your posts if those do not qualify as a answer/solution... which will then lower your reputation making it harder for you to gain the sufficient amount to post comments.

Answer (score 0):

Add Input Hidden textbox after i++;

First get hidden textbox value and add +1 each time row add

When delete hidden textbox value and add -1

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
         if(i>1){
         $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
         i--;
         }
     });
$("#test").text(i);
});
```

In your php page you can pass ahidden variable like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="test" name="test" value="default">
```

and then you can get the value in the hidden field

I think this may help..